# Capistrano cannot load such file -- net/scp (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, digital-ocean

I've got an error while trying to deploy my project on DigitalOcean. When I run command 'cap production deploy' via deploy@ip - got this this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/scp (LoadError)
```

Here is part of my gemfile from local path:

```
 gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11', require: "net-scp"
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'
gem "capistrano-sidekiq"
gem "capistrano-db-tasks", require: false
gem 'net-scp', '~> 3.0'
gem 'net-ssh', '~> 6.1'
```

So as you can see - all of my gems are installed but this error still got me.
Note: but as you see from an error string - it also put the path of old ruby (ruby/2.7.0), so the problem may be on that but I am not sure.

Comment: does `bundle update` run without errors? does it work if you replace `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11', require: "net-scp"` for just `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'`?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your gem file with below gems.

Add this gems in **development group**.

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.10', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.5', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
gem 'capistrano-db-tasks', require: false
```

After that run :-

```
bundle install
```

Then to generates deploy config file run below command in the terminal.

```
 bundle exec cap install
```